# How to use \pause without increasing the index in a beamer?

Tags: beamer, indexing, linguistics, expex

I am using the `expex` package in a beamer file. Every time I use the command `\pause`, all the indices in that frame would increase by one. I would want to know whether there is a way to get rid of it.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{expex}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item Example one
\ex This is the first example.\xe
\pause
\item Example two
\ex This is the second example.\xe
\end{itemize}
\pause
I would like to get rid of the increasing of indices.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```